# Singleton - Undefined?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm trying to get familiar with singleton in sencha, but my getters return me UNDEFINED everytime... Why?  My alert should be displaying 'Bob' but it returns undefined.

here is my handler

```
handler: function(button, event) {
        var user = Prototype.model.Profile;
        alert(user._username);}
```

Here is my singleton

```
Ext.define('Prototype.model.Profile', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

singleton: true,

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'listEvent',
            type: 'auto'
        },
        {
            name: 'listBusiness',
            type: 'auto'
        },
        {
            name: 'listTravel',
            type: 'auto'
        },
        {
            defaultValue: {
                username: 'bob'
            },
            name: 'username'
        }
    ]
},

addTravel: function(newTravel) {

    this._listTravel.push(newTravel);
},

getTravel: function(travelTitle) {

    var travel;

    for(var i=0; i<this._listTravel().getLength(); i++)
    {
        if(this._listTravel[i].getTitle()==travelTitle)
        {
            travel=this._listTravel[i];
            break;
        }
    }


}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think the config part for that should be:

```js
config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'listEvent',
            type: 'auto'
        },
        {
            name: 'listBusiness',
            type: 'auto'
        },
        {
            name: 'listTravel',
            type: 'auto'
        },
        {
            defaultValue: 'bob', // Instead of extra 'username' here
            name: 'username'
        }
    ]
},
```

However, I don't think singletons are meant to be used that way (with Model class). Because singleton will always only create a single instance to your class while your Model objects usually should be independent.

In my opinion, you should only use singleton for util classes. Something that you want to call in any context. Like this:

```js
Ext.define('myApp.utils.AppConfig', {
    singleton: true,
    // Default value declared like this, without the config object
    defaultValue: 'something', 
    alternateClassName: 'AppConfig',
    log: function(text) {
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
            console.log(text);
        }
    }
});
```

Then call it like this in your controllers/views

```js
AppConfig.log('Oh yes ' + AppConfig.defaultValue); // print 'Oh yes something'
```

Comment: I can't validate your answer since I don't work on this project anymore. Sorry :S

The intended behaviour was to be accessible form everywhere as the APP was "rendering" in every tab what the profile of the user was, so instead of having to move the "profile" everywhere I made it a singleton to directly access it and reduce the length of the function calls.

Answer (score 0):

The getters and setters work fine.  It's the default value which is not working properly.
Can't explain why if someone would know, I would accept their answer.